# Backspace & enter button doesn't work on Alert dialog

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog

When i try to erase or enter in edit text inside alertdialog it doesn't work, what gonna wrong with my code? please help me ti fix this issue..
here is my code for the alertdialog :

```
private void showFormBioData(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_bio_data,null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    Button submit = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    final TextView userName = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bioName);
    final TextView shopName = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bioToko);
    final TextView address = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bioAlamat);
    final TextView email = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bioEmail);
    final TextView telp = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bioNope);

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                pdSubmit.show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload to firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     pdSubmit.dismiss();

                }
            },2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your `keylistener`, you returned `true` which mean you have consumed key event. And android will not care about it further.

```
  dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                    return false; // < change this 
                }
            });
```

You can read about this in doc (ctrl + Q in Android Studio or [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener))

```
  /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a key event is
     * dispatched to this dialog. The callback will be invoked before the key
     * event is given to the dialog.
     */
    interface OnKeyListener {
        /**
         * Called when a key is dispatched to a dialog. This allows listeners to
         * get a chance to respond before the dialog.
         *
         * @param dialog the dialog the key has been dispatched to
         * @param keyCode the code for the physical key that was pressed
         * @param event the KeyEvent object containing full information about
         *              the event
         * @return {@code true} if the listener has consumed the event,
         *         {@code false} otherwise
         */
        boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
    }
```